# Spyder modify the template template.py date format

Tags: python, templates, anaconda, spyder

The editor Spyder comes with a default template file template.py, which shows the date parameter "% (date) s", when you create a new py file.
How can I change the date format to the following method "year - month - day hour: minutes: seconds" format, or other format I like?

Answer (score 0):

From [the discussion of this issue](https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/issues/6379#issuecomment-404902109) in Spyder's repository, it appears that `date` is "hard coded in editor.py so you would have to change Spyder code." You can change line 1901 in spyder/spyder/plugins/editor.py to format the date as you desire.

`'date': time.ctime()`